# Ошибка при вызове тестов из subModule в Maven

Tags: java, api, maven, test-automation, testng

Создал мульти модульный проект

Структура проекта следующая:

```
parentModule
|- pom.xml
|- subModulA
|  - pom.xml
|- subModulB
|  - pom.xml
```

parentModule pom.xml

```
<groupId>1</groupId>
<artifactId>autoTest</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>apiTests</module>
    <module>uiTests</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
        <version>0.16</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

subModulA pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>autoTest</artifactId>
        <groupId>1</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>apiTests</artifactId>
```

subModulB pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>autoTest</artifactId>
        <groupId>1</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>uiTests</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>1</groupId>
            <artifactId>apiTests</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

При попытки выполнить команду compile -pl :uiTests test выводит ошибку

```
[INFO] Building uiTests test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.testDependency:apiTests:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Запускать надо из директории модуля

Comment: @RomanC уточните пожалуйста как запустить из директории модуля?